# Network shuts down after sometime

Tags: wifi, internet

I just installed Elementary OS on my ASUS laptop.
The internet (WiFi) seems to stop working (though it shows as connected) after some time of use.
I have noticed this happens when I haven't booted with the charger plugged. [EDIT: nope, it stops either way]

I checked the power management settings by doing an `iwconfig wlan0` and it says power management: off

I have no idea,
I would really love to use elementary OS, but cannot if the internet does not work :(

EDIT: On running `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 9c:5c:8e:1f:82:c6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2104000-b2104fff memory:b2100000-b2103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: c8:ff:28:90:bd:78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.19.0-58-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2000000-b2003fff
```

EDIT:
Works perfectly fine on Windows (so nothing wrong in the BIOS/hardware)

Comment: What's it your wifi card? Try in terminal "sudo lshw -C network" and add the output to your question editing it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. Hope we are able to figure something out!!

Comment: Do you think installing some other proprietary driver will help? If so, how do I go about it? can you help?

Comment: [edit], nope... still crashed

[SOLVED] [NOT REALLY] ... Re-installed the OS...I'm guessing it was one of the updates that messed things up.. DO NOT UPDATE!!

Comment: nope, crashed again!

Comment: Added some aclarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Realtek drivers have so many issues on Ubuntu.  There are some drivers forked by the community, like "*rtlwifi_new*" that you can find at [github.com](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)

**Install instructions**:

From terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot your system and try again.

Source and more info: [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590414/wifi-problems-with-rtl8723be-in-ubuntu-14-04)

If it doesn't work, open a terminal and try  `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` how it's indicated in the link below.